# Help with a PHP Algorithm class

Tags: php, algorithm, oop, class

I'm trying to build a class that will parse CSV files in a certain way.
Unfortunately I am NOT an OO programmer in any way shape or form, my
company is requiring me to write a class for some future functionality
and I seriously, seriously need some help on it. So...

Our $value will be formulated by counting the second marker in the file
which is a semicolon, and create a new feed for each carriage return.

Input is like this:

Code:

> Jeff Goes, Mika Enrar;Triple Threat, Dogs on  Bikes
>
> Sonny Ray, Lars McGarvitch, Jason McKinley;Kasabian, Lords of Acid, Hard-Fi

So for ease of understandability, lets say that the names are $name, the
bands are $item, and the equatible score is $value.

The Run Down:
If the number of letters in the $item is even (Triple Threat = 12)
then the $value is equal to the number of vowels in $name times
one and a half (Jeff Goes [3x1.5] = 4.50)

If the number of the $item is odd (Dogs on Bikes = 11) then the $value
is the number of consonants in $name (Mika Enrar = 5)

If the number of letters in $name share a commonality in $item besides one,
multiply the output by one and a half. So (Sonny Ray = 8; Kasabian = 8;
then 6x1.5 = 9; or lets say $name = 112; $item = 12; we share a commonality of 12)

The idea is to implement a class that assigns each $name a $item to be offered in a way
that maximizes the combined total $value across all of the $item. As a fail safe,
there may be a different number of $name and $item.

My output should be the max $value in two decimal places as in
12.00
38.50

Comment: Why is your company using a non-standard file format?  I think it would be better for you to convince them to use a standard format and if you need a format that you have to set attributes in, maybe XML is what you need.

Comment: `Sonny Ray = 8; Kasabian = 8; then 6x1.5 = 9` is confusing me.  The number of letters in the second part `Kasabian` is even, so isn't the $value to start going to be 3, (S`o`nny R`a`y = 2) * 1.5?  Where are you getting 6?

Comment: The number of Consonants, not vowels, if the $name is an even number. `Sonny Ray = 8 total characters` and also `'S'o'nn'y 'R'ay = 4 total consonants as does 'K'a's'a'b'ia'n'`

Comment: I think you need to go reformat your question.  Add more specific business rules.  After you rewrite the business rules, show an example based on one of the lines demonstrating how it should work.  Using `$name` and `$item` interchangeably with `first portion` and `second portion` is a bit confusing.

Comment: You aren't going to run this on the Book of Daniel, are you?  Cause I think there's a different SO Exchange site for that ...

Comment: @sberry2A reformatted it a bit, and I am NOT running this on the book of daniel

Comment: @ehime:  Do something like this: http://pastie.org/2434767

Comment: @sberry2A that won't work because there is not always and even value of $names and $items I wrote a function already that will parse these into two arrays, but it's NOT OO, I'll post it below

Comment: @sberry2A http://pastie.org/2434797

Comment: @ehime:  So, given that it produces something like this: http://pastie.org/2434909, explain now how your business rules apply.  Note:  I added an extra title to the second line of your example, so you can explain how that would work as well.

Comment: So now that I have then segregated I figure I can do something like this to get counts in a new array http://pastie.org/2434978

Comment: You really need to show what you are expecting.  The code you posted certainly isn't the way to do it.  You have both counters incrementing in the same line ($i and $k) and you are doing a `foreach ($input as $a)` but you are not using `$a` at all.  In your sample code, what is `$input`?  The entire array from the parser, or each sub-array?  **You need to show an example**

Comment: @ehime let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2906/discussion-between-sberry2a-and-ehime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSER**
If you are looking for something a bit more OOP, and to do so with some built-in function of PHP, I would start by doing this:

```
class CSVParser
{

    public $output = NULL;
    public $digits = NULL;

    public function __construct($file)
    {


        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            throw new Exception("$file does not exist");
        }

        $this->contents = file_get_contents($file);
        $this->output = array();
        $this->digits = array();
    }

    public function parse($separatorChar1 = ',', $separatorChar2 = ';', $enclosureChar = '"', $newlineChar = "\n")
    {

        $lines = explode($newlineChar, $this->contents);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            if (strlen($line) == 0) continue;
            $group = array();
            list($part1, $part2) = explode($separatorChar2, $line);
            $group[] = array_map(array($this, "trim_value"), explode($separatorChar1, $part1), array("$enclosureChar \t"));
            $group[] = array_map(array($this, "trim_value"), explode($separatorChar1, $part2), array("$enclosureChar \t"));
            $this->output[] = $group;
        }
    }

    private function trim_value($value, $chars)
    {
        return preg_replace("#^( |" . $chars . ")+#", '', $value);
    }

    public function algorithm()
    {
        $alpha = array(
            'c' => str_split('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'),
            'v' => str_split('aeiouy')
        );
        $i = 0;
        $k = 0;
        foreach ($this->output as $item) {
            $cnt = 0;
            $this->digits[$i] = array();
            foreach ($item as $part) {
                $this->digits[$i][$cnt] = array();
                $new = array();
                foreach ($part as $str) {
                    $v = count(array_intersect(str_split($str), $alpha['v']));
                    $c = count(array_intersect(str_split($str), $alpha['c']));
                    $t = strlen(str_replace(' ', '', $str));
                    $new = array('v' => $v, 'c' => $c, 't' => $t);
                    $this->digits[$i][$cnt][] = $new;
                }
                $cnt++;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
}


$parser = new CSVParser("file.txt");
$parser->parse();
print_r($parser->output);
$parser->algorithm();
print_r($parser->digits);
```

Comment: Sberry that's great, awesome, now I just need to compute averages and see add totals

Comment: Well, since that is the part that I am not understanding, we could chat about it.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2906/discussion-between-sberry2a-and-ehime

Comment: so what I wrote was, I need to **from here** is see if `$parser->digits[0]['t']` is even or odd.
After that I need to either multiply `[0]['v'] * 1.5` if it's even or use `[0]['c']` if it's odd.
if [0] and [1] ['v'] ['c'] or ['t'] are the same number times the previous total by 1.5.
by each commonality I mean, so if `[0]['v'] = 5 and [0']['t'] = 16` and so do the `[1]['v'] and [1]['t']`
that would mean the total would be `$total = $total * 1.5 * 1.5`, and if $total is even, it would be 
`$total = $total * 1.5 * 1.5 * 1.5`